# Remote SSH : no such file or directory

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, ksh

When trying to run this cmd:

```
ssh user@host " cp -f /path1/`cat /path2/file.txt | awk -F : '{printf $4}' `* ../ "
```

got this:

> cat: /path2/file.txt: no such file or directory

Notice that when execute it directly in the server it works

Thanks for any advice

Comment: As a first pointer: I guess your local shell interpretes the `cat ...`. That means everything between the backticks (``) is replaced what is the output of that command on YOUR computer (i think even before the ssh process is started).

Comment: And please provide a bit more information how the files should look like

Comment: Use single quotes for the SSH arguments. And don't use back-ticks at all. They are deprecated. Use `$()` instead.

Comment: @ceving by doing this an error relayed to awk is shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh user@host 'cp -f /path1/$(awk -F : '\''{printf $4}'\'' /path2/file.txt)* ..'
```

This might be also interesting: [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Or this:

```
ssh user@host 'cp -f '\'"$path1"\''/$(awk -F : '\''{printf $4}'\'' /path2/file.txt)* ..'
```

Keep in mind:

- Singe quotes do not evaluate $.
- Double quotes do evaluate $.
- If you want to put a single quote into a single quoted string, you have to split the string in two parts and put an escaped single quote in between. `'a'\''b'` becomes `a'b`
- If you need to evaluate a variable in a single quoted string, you have to split the string in two parts and put the double quoted variable in between. `'a'"$x"'b'` becomes `a${x}b`

Comment: what about making /path1 as a variable from local server ?